# android - send mms in background programatically

Tags: android

In my android application I want to send MMS in background on button click in my android application without user interaction. I am using API level 19 (Android KitKat) Please tell how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the SmsManager's(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) sendMultimediaMessage function.

Comment: I am using API level 19, and `sendMultimediaMessage` is not supported in API level 19